# How to get Screen Time data on macOS?

Tags: macos, time

How can I get the same data that the Screen Time app is returning on macOS?

Specifically I'd like to know — programmatically — the hours I'm spending each day on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 5):

The data screenTime is stored in
/private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge
/Users/wgnb/Library/Application Support/Knowledge

read [Sarah blog for details](https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2018/8/5/knowledge-is-power-using-the-knowledgecdb-database-on-macos-and-ios-to-determine-precise-user-and-application-usage)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment

I've been trying to figure all of this out too.

The closest I've come is this Github Repo: https://github.com/Evian-Zhang/ScreenTimeController

He confirmed the research I had already done by looking at the open file descriptors for the Screen Time agent. The ScreenTime database is stored here:

`/var/folders/XYZ/xxxxxxxxxx/0/com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent/Store`

You can read more about this part of the filesystem [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161204171350/http://www.magnusviri.com:80/OS_X_Admin/what-is-var-folders.html)

In this folder, there are several SQLite files which is what the agent writes to. Unfortunately, this folder is really locked down by MacOS.

You can read about how its locked down [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347192/why-do-i-get-operation-not-permitted-when-i-try-as-root-to-delete-a-file-tha) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x/518545#518545).

The short answer is, as far as I can tell, you can't do it unless you disable System Integrity Protection either for those files or entirely. It is also likely that a software update would break your tweaks and you'd have to re-disable SIP on those files.

It really sucks because ScreenTime aggregates all of my devices and I would love to mess around with the data.